# PHP header(); reliability

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-302

I need to redirect users if I don't want them to be able to access a certain page. How reliable is `header('Location: ../acc/login.php');` for example? Can browsers ignore 302 errors, and is this the right way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't exit the script after that redirect, search engines can ignore it and index the following content.

Comment: 302 is not an error, it is positive response code.

Comment: This is the right way and all modern browsers are supporting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a lot what you're trying to do. Technically spoken, `header()` is *somewhat* reliable. Only somewhat, because many PHP users have problems with it and to not get it to work.

PHP will prevent it from working if output has been already send to the browser. A drastic example:

```
<protected page content here>
<?php
    header('Location: login-first.php');
    exit();
?>
```

This would not work at all. You would eventually see even an error message with a warning.

Headers - by design - need to be send out before any other content (response body). They can not be send any longer if the response body has already started and PHP can't help you then in that case.

However, if you send headers before the response body, that function will work. Also the risk obviously to mess something up is not that drastic any longer, too:

```
<?php
    header('Location: login-first.php');
    exit();
?>
<protected page content here>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rely on `header()`, but make sure you called `die()`, `exit()` or `return` after that. Otherwise, script will continue its execution, which is potential security issue.

Comment: Even if it's somehow blocked by browser, calling `exit()` will stop the script, so there's no security issue.

Comment: Only for *certain* pre-conditions, and OP did not show much code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546392/367456

Answer (score 0):

The browser can ignore `header('Location: ');` forwarding.

That is why you should always return after a call to a header() forward so the rest of your code does not execute should the browser not honor the forwarding.

It is the correct way to do things tho.

Answer (score 0):

I would send the header command and then the exit command "exit()" (to stop running the php code on the server) before displaying the rest of the page. This way the user would never be sent the page content even if they ignored the 302 redirection.

And yes the user can ignore the 302 redirection:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3604591.htm

Comment: Thanks - your answer explained a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`header` is 100% reliable.

However `header('Location: ../acc/login.php')` will be evaluated in the browser to a real location on your website, and ../acc/login.php wil not form a url that is valid!

Comment: Headers are all well and good if the client respects the Location header, else you will get into trouble. Most crawlers won´t respect headers.